# Equivalent of Hibernate SEQUENCE in Sybase ASE 15.5

Tags: hibernate, sybase

I've seen that SEQUENCE is supported in [Sybase IQ](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1601/doc/html/saiq-create-sequence-statement.html)

However is there an alternative in Sybase ASE? This [old forum post](http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1213803-alternative-to-sequence(oracle)-in-sybase) from 2006 suggests suggests using IDENTITY columns, however I'm wondering if there's a more up to date answer.

For context we are supporting multiple database vendors (mainly Oracle) using Hibernate, hence needing to support Sybase as well.

Comment: I just updated the document link, and added some code samples from a Sybase Techwave presentation.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I think IDENTITY will suit our needs.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, you can build your own sequence implementation in ASE using the reserve_identity() function. This is what we did for Oracle-to-ASE migration in the SAP Exodus migration tool (http://scn.sap.com/community/database/blog/2014/07/08/set-your-databases-free--with-exodus). However, we haven't published the details for this, though I hope to be able to do that at some point in the future.